# GNU/Linux: getting value of option 15 of DHCP without using `getnameinfo`

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking, dhcp

My GNU/Linux machine is connected to a DHCP. I want to retrieve the value of the *option 015* of DHCP (DNS Domain Name), but without using `getnameinfo`, since it is using DNS in order to retrieve domain name.

How can I do that with C/C++?

Comment: Broadly speaking, you can only check DHCP options if you are the program speaking to the DHCP server. If you are not, you are limited to getting what the system thinks is it's domain name. That is as it should be, **how** it got the name is an implementation detail you should not care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `dhclient` writes a pile of lease information into `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient-[uuid]-[iface].lease` files. I haven't got a clue what the uuid in those filenames represents, but it does report the different options from the dhcp server.

Answer (score 0):

Fore SUSE: DHCP options are written in /var/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-eth[x].info